# Run the methods of a class from another class

Tags: java, class, methods, invoke

I have four classes in my Java package. Only one class has the `main()` method.

How can I run all the methods in the four classes when the class when I run the `main()` method?

Here are my classes:

*Cat1.java*

```
package test;

public class Cat1 {

    public Cat1() {
        System.out.println("100");
    }

    public Cat1(int i ){
        i = 10;
        System.out.println(" cat1 i :"+ i);
    }
}
```

---

*Cat2.java*

```
package test;

public class Cat2 extends Cat1 {

    public Cat2() {
        System.out.println("200");
    }

    public Cat2(int i ){
        super();
        System.out.println("Cat 2 ; "+ i);
    }
}
```

---

*Cat3.java*

```
package test;

public class Cat3 extends Cat2{

    public Cat3() {
        System.out.println("300");
    }

    public Cat3(int i){
        super();
        System.out.println("Cat 3 : "+ i);
    }

}
```

---

*Sample.java*

```
package test;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Sample {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        //Date d = cal.getTime();
        Locale locale = new Locale("en");
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL, locale);
        System.out.println(" LONg date : " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));

        String incomeData = "200,2,2,2,2";


        int expense = 0;
        String expenseSplit = incomeData;
        System.out.println(" e");
        String expenseArray[] = expenseSplit.split(",");
        String income = expenseArray[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < expenseArray.length; i++) {
            expense = expense+Integer.parseInt(expenseArray[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(" Income "+ income);
        System.out.println(" expense "+ expense);


    }

}
```

Comment: How exactly do you want to run them? Just sequentially from the `main` method?

Comment: You do not have any methods in `Cat*` classes.

Comment: @TAsk I agree - they are just constructors.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just new that object and invoke the function you need.
such as

```
Cat3 cat3 = new Cat3();
```

Or you want call that automatically when main() method run?

Comment: need to call automatically when main() method run

Answer (score 0):

java is an object oriented language, and so if you do not referencing objects, they will just sit there and do nothing.  Within the main method, you can think of that as a starting point where you can create objects, and use them to access methods on them.

Inside you main() method, you can just create some objects..

```
Cat1 sampleCat1 = new Cat1();
Cat1 anotherSampleCat1 = new Cat1(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package test;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat1 cat1 = new Cat1(1);
        Cat2 cat2 = new Cat2(2);
        Cat3 cat3 = new Cat3(3);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        //Date d = cal.getTime();
        Locale locale = new Locale("en");
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL, locale);
        System.out.println(" LONg date : " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));

        String incomeData = "200,2,2,2,2";


        int expense = 0;
        String expenseSplit = incomeData;
        System.out.println(" e");
        String expenseArray[] = expenseSplit.split(",");
        String income = expenseArray[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < expenseArray.length; i++) {
            expense = expense+Integer.parseInt(expenseArray[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(" Income "+ income);
        System.out.println(" expense "+ expense);

    }
}
```

Comment: What should be done if i want to call only some selected methods from other classes?